# How to change color automatically in processing.exe?

Tags: java, graphics, processing

I currently learned about processing.exe. I've made a snake game in processing and I want to modify it. What I want is every time the snake eats food, the food that is moving randomly also gets given random colors.
here's my code:

```
snake s;
int grid = 15;
PVector food;
int r;
int g;
int b;
int warna;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  s = new snake();
  food = new PVector();
  r = (int)random(255);
  g = (int)random(255);
  b = (int)random(255);
  frameRate(15);
  newFood();
}


void draw() {
  background(0);

  s.showScore();
  s.display();
  if (s.gameOver()) {
    background(0);
    textAlign(LEFT);
    textSize(25);
    fill(255);
    text("Game Over", 10, 10, width - 20, 50);
    noLoop();
  }
  if (s.eat(food)) {
    newFood();
  }
  s.move();
  
  fill (r, g, b);
  rect (food.x, food.y, grid, grid);
  
}

void newFood() {

  food.x = floor(random(width));
  food.y = floor(random(height));
  food.x = floor(food.x/grid) * grid;
  food.y = floor(food.y/grid) * grid;
  
  if (food.x == floor(random(width)) && food.y == floor(random(height))){
    fill (r = (int)random(255), g = (int)random(255), b = (int)random(255));
    rect( food.x, food.y, grid, grid);
    
  }
 
  
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode == UP) {
    s.arah(0, -1);
  } else if (keyCode == DOWN) {
    s.arah(0, 1);
  } else if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
    s.arah(1, 0);
  } else if (keyCode == LEFT) {
    s.arah(-1, 0);
  }
}


And this are the snake :



class snake {
  float x = 0;
  float y = 0;
  float xspd = 1;
  float yspd = 0;
  int panjang = 0;
  ArrayList<PVector> body =  new ArrayList<PVector>();

  snake() {
  }

  boolean eat(PVector pos) {
    float d = dist(x, y, pos.x, pos.y);
    if (d < 1) {
      panjang++;
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  void arah(float x, float y) {
    xspd = x;
    yspd = y;
  }

  boolean gameOver() {
    for (int i = 0; i < body.size(); i++) {
      PVector pos = body.get(i);
      float d = dist(x, y, pos.x, pos.y);
      if (d < 1) {
        panjang = 0;
        body.clear();
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }


  void move() {
    if (panjang > 0) {
      if (panjang == body.size() && !body.isEmpty()) {
        body.remove(0);
      }
      body.add(new PVector(x, y));
    }

    x = x + xspd*grid;
    y = y + yspd*grid;

    x = (x + width) % width;
    y = (y + height) % height;
  }

  void display() {
    noStroke();
    fill(255);
    for (PVector bagi : body) {
      rect(bagi.x, bagi.y, grid, grid);
    }
    rect(x, y, grid, grid);
  }

  void showScore() {
    textAlign(LEFT);
    textSize(25);
    fill(255);
    text("Score: " + body.size(), 10, 10, width - 20, 50);
  }
}
```

I've tried to change the color with declare r, g, b and assign a random color to it. But the food color doesn't seem to change every time the snake eats the food. Any suggestions on what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

You're doing good so far. The only part you missed is that you want to change the food's color *when you create some new food*. So... you just have to take this part of the `setup()` method:

```
  r = (int)random(255);
  g = (int)random(255);
  b = (int)random(255);
```

and move it in the `newFood()` method.

Hope this helps. Have fun!